# Entity Framework and SQL Server Tuning Advisor

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

How do I use SQL Server Tuning Advisor to produce recommendations based on Entity Framework queries? Entity Framework uses sp_executesql 'query' instead of executing the query and Tuning Advisor does not recognize these queries. I could get the query text manually, but this will only work for very simple scenarious. How do I do it in an automatic way?

**UPDATE**

Would it help if I save the profiling information into a table and then run some application which will strip "sp_executesql" and only keep the query text and use this new data to run Tuning Advisor?

Comment: I like this question. It should be asked on MS Connect as well, because current SQL generator is not very good and this is only one of many problems.

Comment: I am still having problems with this. I've tried all the suggestions below. Difficult to find any good information about the subject too..

Answer (score 6):

I know this topic is a little cold. But since I was having the same issue and found a better solution:

Changing events captured is one way to do it, but there is already a "template", which records everything needed by the SQL server tuning advisor.

If you select the template "tuning", it will effectively remove and add event capture quoted by Doug, but another too.

You can find more about template [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190176.aspx)

To activate this template, in the "New Trace" windows, select the corresponding template( I didn't create it, it was already there):
[image: New trace properties]

Once you did it, you can check the event selection, you have already what is needed:
[image: Trace event selection]

I additionaly disabled the RPCCompleted, since I've no stored procedure

I hope it will help some people ;)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the problem is this.  If you create a trace using SQL Profiler from the "Tuning" template it does not include the correct events.  The Database Engine Tuning Advisor does not understand `sp_executsql` statements from the batch completed events.  It report in the tuning log "Event does not reference any tables" with a category ID of "S008".

**When capturing your trace you need to add the "SQL:StmtCompleted" event  under the TSQL section as well.**

Answer (score 2):

Jeff Walker pointed me in the right direction - but his answer was incomplete (although I'm certain he knew the complete answer and just didn't fully explain it)

**In the Event Selection for Sql Server Profiler:**

Remove the logging of RPC:Completed under Stored Procedures - this is the item that does poorly with Entity Framework

Expand to all events and ADD SP:StmtCompleted under Stored Procedure in order to get the queries into the trace.

Seems to work for me.

**Microsoft Entity Framework People (and profiler people) This is actually lame.  It used to work.**

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Profiler to capture a whole session of queries.  When you're done you can save the profiler results and run the whole thing through SQL Server Tuning Advisor.  In my experience this gives much better results than tuning based on individual queries and in many ways is easier and more realistic since you can use profiler to capture queries from real application usage.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for bringing more attention to the specific issue you're asking about.  I didn't realize you were saying that the Tuning Advisor doesn't understand `sp_executesql` because that simply isn't true.  You can run as many queries as you want through `sp_executesql` and capture them in a profile and then run that profile through Tuning Advisor and it will give you recommendations.

To be sure, I just did it with MS SQL Server 2008 R2.  I created a table with no indexes, ran a bunch of queries through `sp_executesql`, captured them in SQL Profiler, and then ran the resulting trace through Tuning Advisor.  Tuning Advisor gave appropriate recommendations for the queries embedded within `sp_executesql`.

The exact version of Database Engine Tuning Advisor is 10.50.1600.1, running against Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)   Apr 22 2011 19:23:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1).

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.  The problem is that EF issues sp_executesql commands, which the tuning advisor does not understand.

Comment: @Craig, you're right, I didn't understand, but that's because the premise isn't true.  The question is asking what to do since Tuning Advisor doesn't understand `sp_executesql`, but Tuning Advisor actually does understand `sp_executesql` fine using the procedure I described above.

Comment: I think if you're analyzing SQL Server Profiler output, Log individual statements and not just batches and I think you will get the right output you need to make recommendations.

Comment: @Ted Elliott, in my testing I received recommendations from both results with individual statements as well as batches of statements.